# Xamarin iOS : Webview navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my ios xamarin app , I want to navigate from one page in webview to another 
(http://a ==> http://a/b)

I am able to do by

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("window.location.href = 'http://a/b';", null);
```

The issue is the url ("http://a/b") is not hardcoded so I want to pass parameter. Can anyone help me on how I can do it?

I tried

```
var x = "http://a/b";
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("window.location.href = ''+x;", null);
```

But it doesn't work can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found a way:

```
var x = "http://a/b";
var url = (string.Format("window.location.href = '{0}';", x));
webView.EvaluateJavaScript(url, null);
```